# Capacity of Vectors?

Tags: c++, vector

According to c++ reference, vector's .capacity() function returns the "size of allocated storage capacity".

Doesn't this mean that a vector {1} should have capacity of sizeof(1) like an array?
If so, then why does this code:

```
int main() {
  vector<int> v = {1};
  cout << v.capacity() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

produce 1 rather than 4(sizeof(v[0]))?

I just started learning c++, so forgive me if I sound foolish.

Comment: Unlike `sizeof`, `vector::capacity` returns the number of _elements_, not the number of bytes.

Comment: `std::vector::capacity` returns the _number of elements_ the container has space for, not the number of allocated bytes.

Comment: Where exactly did you quote this sentence from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `capacity()` of a vector is better expressed as "the amount of space currently set aside that can be used for storage", expressed in terms of the number of potential elements that can be stored. Note that like `size()`, this is the number of *elements*, not the number of *bytes*.

For example, a vector might have a `size()` of 3 and a `capacity()` of 4: this says that it is currently storing 3 elements, and has room for a maximum of 4 elements (total) before it will need to reallocate.

On the other hand, `sizeof` returns the number of bytes required for an object of the given type, and is determined at compile time. For example, if you want the number of bytes currently allocated by the vector for storage, you could do `vector.capacity() * sizeof(vector[0])`.

Comment: Does there exist a function for vector that returns the "space set aside for storage"? Would sizeof(vector_name) work?

Comment: @timg no; `sizeof(vector_name)` is equivalent to e.g. `sizeof(std::vector<int>)`; this will always be a compile-time constant—most likely the size of three pointers on your system. There is no dedicated member function to get the total size in bytes of the allocated storage; however, as I mentioned, you can combine `std::vector<T>::capacity()` and `sizeof(T)` to calculate it yourself if you require it for some reason.

Comment: Why is doing sizeof(vector_name) different from doing sizeof(array_name)?

Comment: @timg Because a vector is just a few pointers to dynamically allocated memory stuck elsewhere; an array is a stack-allocated type with static size. If you are confused about what `sizeof` actually does probably ask a new question, or see if you can find some information to clarify it. Again, remember, `sizeof` is an operation done _entirely at compile time_.